# Class loading issue PHPUnit test

Tags: php, phpunit

I am following [Getting Started with PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html)  using the following code:

**tests\MoneyTest.php**

```
<?php

class MoneyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
// ...

public function testCanBeNegated()
{
    // Arrange
    $a = new Money(1);

    // Act
    $b = $a->negate();

    // Assert
    $this->assertEquals(-1, $b->getAmount());
}

// ...
}
```

**src\Money.php**

```
 {{{
 <?php
 class Money
{
private $amount;

public function __construct($amount)
{
    $this->amount = $amount;
}

public function getAmount()
{
    return $this->amount;
}

public function negate()
{
    return new Money(-1 * $this->amount);
}

// ...
}

}}}
```

When I run `phpunit tests/MoneyTest` I get the follwing message:

```
PHPUnit 4.8.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E

Time: 56 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) MoneyTest::testCanBeNegated
Error: Class 'Money' not found

/srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-content/plugins/x-helloworld/tests/MoneyTest.php:10

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
vagrant@vvv:/srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-content/plugins/x-helloworld$
```

How do I get the class file from ..\src be recognized be the reference in the test tests\MoneyTest.php?

**UPDATE:**

Version and OS listed:

```
php --version
PHP 7.0.8-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
phpunit --version
PHPUnit 4.8.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

Comment: Did you check it with the complete source code _You can find the complete sourcecode of the MoneyTest class here._ written just below the code samples.\

Comment: No I did not.  The site shows an extracted example which should work.  The examples are a bit out of data, and I had to modify the extends statement.  A class not found error indicates to me any test, even the complete source code, would still fail on that class dependency. Its a trivial example, and not sure how PHP expect should find the class.

But I will do that and confirm the results Thanks

Comment: The complete tests as written give the following error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /srv/www/wordpress-default/wp-content/plugins/x-helloworld/tests/MoneyTest.php on line 12.

Comment: I had to use the 'class MoneyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' extends syntax to correct this problem.  The allows the test case class to be properly referenced, and actually begin the test.  The test then fails with the Error: Class 'Money' not found message.  Given the example I provided, how would I change the code or configuration so that class resolves from the test code?